# Browser crashes after uploading around 150 photos

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, html5-canvas, jquery-file-upload

I am working on an application where we are uploading around 200-300 images using jquery fileupload. Before uploading i need to resize it using canvas in browser to reduce server load.
But page crashes after like uploading around 150 photos and getting error `Aww snap! smoething went wrong`

Here is javascript code that I am using to resize and upload files,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  function formatBytes(bytes, decimals = 2) {
    if (bytes === 0) return '0 Bytes';

    const k = 1024;
    const dm = decimals < 0 ? 0 : decimals;
    const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];

    const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));

    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
  }


  /* Utility function to convert a canvas to a BLOB */
  var dataURLToBlob = function(dataURL) {
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
      var parts = dataURL.split(',');
      var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
      var raw = parts[1];

      return new Blob([raw], {type: contentType});
    }

    var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    var rawLength = raw.length;

    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
      uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([uInt8Array], {type: contentType});
  }
  /* End Utility function to convert a canvas to a BLOB      */

  $("#fileupload").change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loader_image, .loader_text').removeClass('hide');
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
      var file = this.files[i];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (readerEvent) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function (imageEvent) {

          // Resize the image
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            max_size = 1600,// TODO : pull max size from a site config
            width = image.width,
            height = image.height;
          if (width > height) {
            if (width > max_size) {
              height *= max_size / width;
              width = max_size;
            }
          } else {
            if (height > max_size) {
              width *= max_size / height;
              height = max_size;
            }
          }
          canvas.width = width;
          canvas.height = height;
          canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
          var mimeType = image.src.match(/[^:]\w+\/[\w-+\d.]+(?=;|,)/)[0];
          var ext = image.src.match(/[^:/]\w+(?=;|,)/)[0];
          var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL(mimeType);
          var resizedImage = dataURLToBlob(dataUrl);

          image_html = '<div class="col-sm-2 sm-margin-bottom-30 image_subcontainer" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" data-filename="'+imageEvent.target.name+'"><p class="album-btn" align="right" style=""><a class="remove_photo" role="button" style="color:grey;" rel="nofollow" href="#">&nbsp;</a></p><p></p><a href="#" class="fancybox img-hover-v1"><span style="height: 140px; padding-top: 14px;"><img src="'+image.src+'"></span></a><div style="text-align: center;margin-bottom: 30px;">'+imageEvent.target.name+'</div> <div id="progress" class="col-sm-2 sm-margin-bottom-27" style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div><span class="data_loaded"></span></div></div>'

          $('.images_fancybox').prepend(image_html);
          $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: [new File([resizedImage], imageEvent.target.name)]})
        }
        image.name = readerEvent.target.fileName;
        image.src = readerEvent.target.result;
      }
      reader.fileName = file.name;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  });


  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
      var fileType = data.files[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), allowdtypes = 'jpeg,jpg,png';
      if (allowdtypes.indexOf(fileType) < 0) {
        alert('Invalid file type '+fileType+'. Allowed file types: jpeg,jpg,png ');
        return false;
      }
      if(data.fileInput == undefined){
        data.submit()
      }
      // console.log(data);
    },
    start: function (e) {
      // progressBar = '<div id="progress" class="col-sm-2 sm-margin-bottom-30"><div class="bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 0%;"></div></div>'
      // $('#progress_bar').append(progressBar);
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
      if(data.loaded == data.total){
        $('.loader_image, .loader_text').addClass('hide');
      }
    },
    progress: function (e, data) {

      var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
      $('div[data-filename="'+data.files[0].name+'"] #progress .bar, div[data-filename="'+data.files[0].name+'"] #progress').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
      );

      $('div[data-filename="'+data.files[0].name+'"] #progress .data_loaded').text(formatBytes(data.loaded) + "/" + formatBytes(data.total))

    },
    done: function (e, data) {
      if(data.result.success){
        var uploaded_image = imageContainer(data.result.id, data.result.album_id, data.result.filename, data.result.fileurl, data.result.authenticity_token)
        // $('div[data-filename="'+data.result.filename+'"]').remove();
        // $('.images_fancybox').prepend(uploaded_image);
        $('div[data-filename="'+data.files[0].name+'"]').replaceWith(uploaded_image);
        SP.Photo.bindEvents();
        SP.Photo.initNoteForm();
        SP.App.initFancybox();
      }else{
        $('.container_wrapper .flash_messages').html(data.result.error_html)
      }
    },
    fail: function(e, data){
      console.log(data);
    },
    always: function(e, data){
      console.log(data);
    },
  });


  function imageContainer(id, album_id, filename, fileurl, authenticity_token){
    return '<div class="col-sm-2 sm-margin-bottom-30 image_subcontainer" data-photo-id="'+id+'" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><p class="album-btn" align="right" style=""><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete photo" class="remove_photo tooltips glyphicon glyphicon-remove" role="button" data-confirm="Your are attemtping to delete a photo. Press "Ok" to delete or "Cancel" to cancel the request." style="color:grey;" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/photographer/albums/'+album_id+'/photos/'+id+'"></a><a data-id="'+id+'" class="add_note_btn add_note_'+id+' pull-left glyphicon glyphicon-edit " style="color:grey;" href="#" data-original-title="" title=""></a></p><div style="display: none;" class="add_note_class_'+id+'"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><form class="note_form" data-id="'+id+'" id="edit_photo_'+id+'" action="/photographer/albums/'+album_id+'/photos/'+id+'" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="'+authenticity_token+'"><fieldset><div id="status-area" data-id="'+id+'"></div><div class="row"><section class="col col-12"><textarea rows="3" style="resize:vertical;" class="form-control note_input_'+id+'" name="photo[photographer_note]" id="photo_photographer_note"></textarea></section></div></fieldset><br><fieldset><div class="row"><img class="loader_image hide pull-left" src="/assets/loader.gif" alt="Loader" width="30" height="30"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-disable-with="Submit"></div></fieldset></form></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"></div></div></div></div><p></p><a href="'+fileurl+'" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="'+filename+'" class="fancybox img-hover-v1" title="'+filename+'" id="'+id+'" data-user="suggested" data-album-id="'+album_id+'"><span style="height: 140px; padding-top: 14px;"><img class="img-responsive" src="'+fileurl+'"></span></a><!-- word-wrap: break-word; --><div style="text-align: center;">'+filename+'</div><div style="padding-bottom: 30px;"><a data-id="suggested_'+id+'" class="suggested_'+id+'" data-remote="true" href="/photographer/albums/'+album_id+'/photos/'+id+'/suggest"><button type="button" class=" btn-warning pull-left btn-circle"><i class="glyphicon "></i></button></a><a href="#"><button type="button" class=" btn-success pull-right btn-circle"><i class="glyphicon "></i></button></a></div></div>'
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you really need to process them all at the same time? A few things: you don't need a single dataURI here, which will make your file be allocated thrice in the memory for no good, instead work with blobs and blobURIs (canvas has a toBlob() method). Reuse the canvas element, generating one means that all its bitmap is being allocated to memory, if you do it too much the GC may not have the time to clean correctly. Note that in newest browsers (the ones supporting OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D) you could move everything to a WebWorker.  (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) But all these won't go against the fact that 300 1600x1600px images in memory at the same time is just a lot. So really, **the** point you should take into consideration is if you really need to process them all as once, instead of for instance uploading only a batch of 5 then only process the next batch. (and also, have you considered doing the resize server-side? Canvas is very bad at resizing images if what you wish is to save space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this myself. The problem was with FileReader.
This needed to clear filereader. So by adding following it fixes my problem.

```
reader.onloadend = function(image) {
  image.src= '';
}
```